# How to solve n*log2(n)=A in matlab?

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

`n*log2(n) = A`, with `A` a known value. How do I solve for `n` in Matlab? Note that `n` isn't necessary an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or [solve the equation analytically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%2alog2%28n%29=A) and use that:

```
n = A*log(2)/lambertw(A*log(2))
```

Comment: My preference too, but of course this requires the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: I had to look. There is a lambertw tool on the FEX. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3644-real-values-of-the-lambert-w-function

Answer (score 2):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can use [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)

```
n = fmincon(@(N) abs(N*log2(N)-A),10, [],[],[],[],1,Inf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `fzero`:

```
solution = fzero(@(n) n.*log2(n)-A, A/5);
```

I found the initial guess empirically by examining the solution's behaviour on the interval 0-1000; you might want to adjust it for your use case.

Comment: that was my first though, but it will fail if A is close to 1

Comment: @Rasman: not here: `solution = 1.559610469462369e+00` Why do you think it will fail near `A=1`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Symbolic Math Toolbox installed, all you need is:

```
solve('n*log2(n)=A', 'n')

ans =
    (A*log(2))/lambertw(0, A*log(2))
```

You can also use `solve` with `syms`:

```
syms n A

solve(n*log2(n)==A, n)
```

After `syms n A` you can also define the value of `A`:

```
A = 0
solve(n*log2(n)==A, n)

ans =
    1

A = 2
solve(n*log2(n)==A, n)

ans =
    2

A = 3
solve(n*log2(n)==A, n)

ans =
    (3*log(2))/lambertw(0, 3*log(2))
```